# Setting different formatting for mouseover and select in OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, styles, hover, openlayers, mouseover

I have a vector Layer in Open layers. http://www.geos.ed.ac.uk/~s0825955/cgi-bin/maps6.pl

When selected it uses the selected formatting intent and also brings up a popup. I want the selected formatting to be displayed when the mouse moves over the layer, and the popup to display only when the feature is clicked.

I have tried adding `{hover: true}` to the `SelectFeature` control but this makes the popups appear as you move the mouse over the map.

I have also tried adding a second feature control that the popup doesn't listen to but the style map doesn't recognize this either.

Is there any way I can have a different style for hovering that does not have the feature selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one SelectFeature control may be active at a time, unless the second one has the property `highlightOnly = true`. From the OpenLayers docs:

> [highlightOnly](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/SelectFeature-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature.highlightOnly){Boolean} - 
>   If true do not actually select features (that is place them in the layer’s selected features array), just highlight them.

Try adding a second SelectFeature control that just changes the style. It should look like this:

```
var hover_feature_control = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(
    [your_layer],
    {
        hover: true,
        highlightOnly: true,
        renderIntent: "temporary"
    }
);
```

The renderIntent property should match the name of the style you want on hover in the style map.

```
    styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
        'default': default_marker_style,
        'temporary': hover_marker_style
    })
```

Make sure you remove `{hover: true}` from the control that manages popups!